# Trying to print address of the variable of an object that is an element of array

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, reference

I'm using this code to get the address of the 'b' variable. Is this a way of doing it?

```
printf("%p \n",&r[1].b);
```

r is declared as an array that stores objects of type 'C'. Objects of type C have variables a,b, and x. I'm trying to get the address of b, which is an int.

Another question.. is it possible to generalize the code so that I can get and print the address of any object, regardless of their type?

Comment: Just edited the post, this is for C++.

Comment: Can anyone offer assistance?

Comment: Looks okay to mean, in isolation without seeing any other code.

Comment: Nitpick: You might like to use iostreams unless you have some specific reason not to ;)

Comment: @BrandiNo: What assistance do you need? This will print the address of `r[1].b`, and will work for any type (unless it's overloaded `operator&` in some evil manner).

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks OK.
To generalize, you need a template

```
template <class T> void printAddressOf(T const &t)
{
    printf("%p \n", &t);
}
```

Or, a macro:

```
#define PRINTADDRESS(t) (printf("%p \n", &(t)))
```

These work in most simple cases.
It's more trouble when "T" overloads operator&() - you have to do some more template tricks to get around that. Some implementations of std::vector<> will do that.